# gRaphael : How to make border color for barchat?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael, graphael

Is there any solution to make border-color for bar chart in g.raphael ?

Here is my script

```
efficiency.barchart(0, 200, 400, 150, [
    [10, 5, 32, 13, 2, 55, 8]
], {
    vgutter: 0,
    colors: ["#F58A2A"],
        "gutter": "0%"
});
```

Simply needed black `border` for left, top and right 
Like this

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/u4qzB/4/

Comment: Where do you want the border. In each bar? Or in the container.

Comment: @Steve like the image one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply attributes to the bars directly within barchart:

```
efficiency.barchart(0, 0, 400, 150, [
  [55, 20, 13, 32, 5, 1, 10]
], {
  type: 'soft',
  //vgutter: 5,
  stretch: true,
  colors: ["#F00"],
}).bars.attr({
  stroke: "#000",
  "stroke-width":1
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no option to use border in the `barchart`, you can see it on the documentation:
http://g.raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.barchart

If you really want to force borders in all the cases, i would recommend you to modify some lines in the `js` files. (`g.raphael.js` and `g.bar.js`)
Look for the text `stroke` and instead of `none`, add something. (not sure how stroke works but you can see it on the [SVG documetnation](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#StrokeProperty).)